# Onenote 2007 - losing data

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote-2007

I have been keeping copious notes in OneNote2007.  Recently, I've had two instances of data loss.  The most recent involved keeping the main OneNote files on a NAS server, which I had been primarily accessing from a single desktop.  I changed over to a newer desktop, and when I open my file from there, it is missing roughly 1 week of the latest OneNote data.

The funny thing, the current data still shows when I open the same file on the old computer.

I'm wondering:

1. How can I get all my data to show on the new computer?
2. How reliable is Onenote2007 if it so easily loses data like this?  Wherever I record my notes, it pretty much needs to be rock-solidly reliable.

EDIT - More info:
When I try a manual sync, it says "This notebook is not connected.  Changes are not being synchronized.".  When I go to Tools-Options-Save-Paths, I changed backup and default notebook location to the network share.  It won't let me change the unfiled notes section, and the cache is still local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you loose the synchronization ability on one of the computers? It doesn't sound like you had actual data loss in this case, just unsynchronized data.

Comment: I tend to shut down the computers at night...but then turn them on again in the morning.  I wonder if I disconnect things before it synchronizes, if it may "forget" to synchronize when the connection is re-established.  Any idea how to force a sync?

Comment: If you right click on the notebook name from within OneNote, there should be a menu item to synchronize the notebook. I know this is true on OneNote 2010, and I seem to remember it from 2007 too.

Comment: Thanks, I found it but ran into issues--see edits to question.

Comment: OK--I zeroed in on File-Sync and reset the file location (didn't change it, just reset to the same value), and finally got it to sync!

Answer (score 0):

OneNote makes use of parts of the SMB protocol (e.g. range locks) that some NAS boxes (which typically run some version of Linux + Samba) do not implement reliably.